# randomly reading a file with mapviewoffile

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a very large file that I would like to use CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile to extract 10 bytes of text from it based on a given identifier number. So here is what I have tried in vain,

```
char* Read(char*pFilename, int id)
{
    HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(pFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    DWORD dwSysGran = sysInfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
    DWORD dwFileMapStart = ((id*10/ dwSysGran)*dwSysGran);
    DWORD dwMapViewSize = (id*10 % dwSysGran) + 10;
    DWORD dwFileMapSize = id*10 + 10;
    char data[10];
    HANDLE hMap = ::CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, dwFileMapSize, NULL);
    if (hMap != NULL)
    {
        char *rawBuffer = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, dwFileMapStart, dwMapViewSize);
        memcpy(&data[0], rawBuffer, 10);
        UnmapViewOfFile(rawBuffer);
    }
//...
    return data;
}
```

For example, if the user inputs a file named "characterWeaponData.ucc" and `an identifier = 122`
then my program needs to read 10 bytes of text starting from 1220 th byte in the file on and return them for further processing.

I wrote this code solely based on several resources I found on SO and until now I have had no single thorough idea of what on earth

```
_In_     DWORD  dwFileOffsetHigh,
 _In_     DWORD  dwFileOffsetLow,
```

in these two functions really mean to do. And I guess my parameters passed into these as in the above program shows are incorrect.

Comment: Why use memory mapping for this when you can open the file and seek to the offset you're interested in?

Comment: 64 bit number split into two 32 bit values, the **high**est 32 bits and the **low**est 32 bits.

Comment: But what are they for and how to use them in this case ?

Comment: @molbdnilo because I now love to use winapi only.

Comment: You can read from a file using the Win32 API.

Comment: Thank you I am expecting a solution using MapViewOfFile.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the file is all *that* large.  If you can make your application 64-bit, you could simply map the entire file into memory and read from your offset.  The main advantage of doing it that way is that you can keep the file mapped permanently, rather than reopening it and remapping it with every call to Read().  Significantly faster.

Comment: The winapi is 25 years old, support for 64-bit integral types in C compilers was not yet common back then.  Simply declare a LARGE_INTEGER variable, assign QuadPart and its LowPart and HighPart members give you the values you want to pass.

Comment: @molbdnilo - `and seek to the offset ` - what sense in seek at all when we can direct read at offset without senseless seek ?

Comment: @RbMm: Seek and read is easier to read, debug, and implement. No need to complicate things by opening the file for asynchronous I/O, allocate and prepare an `OVERLAPPED` structure, and synchronization with the I/O. There are cases, where this is well justified. This is not one of those cases.

Comment: @IInspectable - file **must not be open for asynchronous I/O** for use direct file offset - are you don't know this ? this worked for any file open type. what is more simply and main **more effective** - use additional argument in call or do additional call to kernel with 1000*x instructions.. `and synchronization with the I/O. ` - you are about ? you wrong here

Comment: `allocate and prepare an OVERLAPPED` - simply declare it as local variable in stack too hard ? i however at all use ZwReadFile always instead ReadFile )

Comment: @IInspectable - you completely wrong when say that file need be opened as asynchronous for use `OVERLAPPED`. this is use for synchronous handles to . even read from msdn - `If hFile is not opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and lpOverlapped is not NULL, the read operation starts at the offset that is specified in the OVERLAPPED structure`.

Comment: @RbMm: I wasn't commenting on the accuracy of your statement, just your overall attitude. There's a difference in saying *"are you don't know this ?"* and *"this seems to be wrong"*, beyond one of them being real English.

Comment: @IInspectable - your problem that you never can admit that you mistaken. in this case you mistake about using `OVERLAPPED` (only with asynchronous I/O). use direct offset in `OVERLAPPED` - need less src code, more simply and much more effective that call `SetFilePointerEx`.

Comment: @RbMm: I usually don't have to. Speaking about admitting mistakes: *"[It is] much more effective that call `SetFilePointerEx`"* - No, it's not. It's **equally** effective, and possibly marginally more efficient. Not the kind of optimization I would implement when it sacrifices readability, ease of use, and maintainability. Certainly not here.

Comment: @IInspectable - you again completely wrong. it is **less** effective use `SetFilePointerEx` because additional call to kernel. i you still not accept that you was wrong in first your comment about overlapped

Comment: @RbMm: No, it is **equally** effective. In case that previous comment didn't trigger your curiosity: Look up the difference between effectiveness and efficiency in your favorite dictionary. And for reference: Yes, you can pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure to a synchronous `ReadFile` call, and claiming that you couldn't was a mistake.

Comment: @IInspectable - no - additional call to kernel (`SetFilePointerEx`) this is additional 1000*x instructions to execute. without this call - I/O manager simply get file offset or direct from call parameter (yes it validate if call from UserMode but this is several instruction only) or from `FILE_OBJECT` - so this is **NOT equally effective** - and again you wrote about `asynchronous I/O` in first own comment and now can not admit that you mistake

Comment: @RbMm: that's not what the word "effective" means.  Both solutions provide the exact same data, and speed is clearly not one of the OPs requirements, so IInspectable is correct in saying that the two solutions are equally effective.  I don't know why he brought it up, but he is correct in saying that "effective" wasn't the right word.  (Personally I think using OVERLAPPED would be just as readable as seeking in this case, perhaps even a little more so.  But it really doesn't matter, particularly as the OP wants to do it with a memory mapping anyway.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston this is not related to OP question at all. i simply note that no sense call `SetFilePointerEx` when can direct set offset un API call. until comments not delete you can see that at begin Ins* say that this require asynchronous I/O what is wrong. about effective - call `SetFilePointerEx` this is additional call to kernel. and if be correct need check result of this call (what if it fail, because file size smaller for example). but this call is excess. so i and say that use explicit file offset undoubtedly more effective. of course different in single call negligible. but exist.

Comment: @RbMm, that still isn't what the word "effective" means.  I'm not disputing any of the technical details.  But your argument compares the *efficiency* of the two approaches, or perhaps the *elegance*, not the *effectiveness*.  (I suspect the distinction doesn't translate well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations look correct, but you forgot that the view at `rawBuffer` is pointing to the offset `dwFileMapStart` rather than to `id*10`.

I'd try something like this:

```
char* Read(char*pFilename, int id)
{
    HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(pFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    DWORD dwSysGran = sysInfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
    DWORD dwSize = 10;
    DWORD dwOffset = id*dwSize;
    DWORD dwFileMapStart = ((dwOffset/dwSysGran)*dwSysGran);
    DWORD dwMapViewSize = dwOffset + dwSize - dwFileMapStart;
    char data[10];
    HANDLE hMap = ::CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (hMap != NULL)
    {
        char *rawBuffer = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, dwFileMapStart, dwMapViewSize);
        memcpy(&data[0], rawBuffer + (dwOffset - dwFileMapStart), dwSize);
        UnmapViewOfFile(rawBuffer);
    }
//...
    return data;
}
```

(I haven't tested this code so there may be a few typos.  But it should give you the basic idea.)

If the file might be larger than 4GB, you would need to do a 64-bit calculation.

Note that (depending on the file size and the bitness of your application) it would probably make more sense to maintain a permanent mapped view of the entire file than to create a new mapping each time you need to read 10 bytes.  At least consider maintaining a permanent mapping object even if you want to remap the view each time; you'll find it reduces overhead significantly.

Comment: Thank you @Harry Johnston. The program outputs correctly now. ~))

Answer (score 1):

1. There is little reason to use a file mapping here. Open, seek, and read. File mappings aren't magically faster.
2. `dwFileOffsetHigh` and `dwFileOffsetLow` combine to a 64 bit offset into the file where the "View" begins. You can havbe multiple views of a single file mapping, starting at different offsets. The offset must be a multiple of the page size. So you cannot make it start whereever you want
3. `dwFileMapSize` (high and low are a 64 bit value) must be the maximum size of the file available in the mapping.
4. Disk failure and disk removal may cause a (system) exception. You would need to handle that if you don't want your program to crash in this situation.
5. Note that your offset specification allows for a 10-byte segment to cross a page boundary. You would have to make sure your view stretches two pages